# Какой размер баннера выбрать для микроразметки?

Tags: html, вёрстка, веб-дизайн, микроразметка

Делаю небольшое веб-приложение, у которого в шапке находится баннер, что-то типа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотел поинтересоваться, а какой размер баннера должен быть, чтобы эта картинка беспроблемно подцеплялась в микроразметку для социальных сетей и мессенджеров (практически везде сейчас есть такая вещь, как превью ссылок: кидаешь ссылку - а тебе её развернут в плашку с картинкой и описанием сайта).

Видел когда-то статью на Хабре про микроразметку, но не могу сейчас найти.

Находятся только какие-то статьи с перечислением требований конкретных соц. сеток, [например у тильды](http://tilda.education/articles-images-for-social).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашёл статью, которая засела в памяти: [Крутой шаринг страниц в соцсети с помощью Open Graph](https://habr.com/post/278459/)

Там даны следующие рекомендации:

> Выбор картинки подходящего размера — основная проблема. Даже внутри
>   одной соцсети есть сценарии, в которых изображения безбожно кропятся.
>   Раньше я пользовался [специальным
>   шаблоном](http://share.ivanzolotov.s3.amazonaws.com/2016/habr_og.sketch),
>   чтобы понять, как откадрировать изображение и гарантированно не
>   потерять главного.
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> А потом я просто подсмотрел, как делают на Слоне.
>
> Да, 968×504 пискеля это меньше минимально рекомендованных Фейсбуком
>   1200×630. Зато при таком размере и ратио картинку нигде не кропят, и
>   выглядит она отлично.

Answer (score 3):

Ответ уже имеется в вашем вопросе по [вашей же ссылке](http://tilda.education/articles-images-for-social):

> **Если погружаться в тонкости не хочется совсем, запомните один размер: 1024 x 512 px**. *В большинстве случаев такая картинка будет отображаться корректно*. Либо можно воспользоваться [сервисами, которые сделают картинку правильного размера](http://tilda.education/articles-images-for-social#tools) за вас.
>
> Далее: таблица с наиболее важными параметрами основных социальных сетей.
>
> **Размеры изображений**
>
> ```
>      FACEBOOK
>      Картинка к внешним ссылкам: 1200 x 630 px
>      Картинка для поста: 1200 x 630 px
>      Обложка: 820 х 312 px
>      Фото профиля: 170х170 px
>
>      ВКОНТАКТЕ
>      Картинка к внешним ссылкам: 537 x 240 px
>      Картинка для поста: 700 x 500 px
>      Фото профиля: 200 х 500 px
>
>      TWITTER
>      Картинка для твита: 1024 x 512 px
>      Обложка: 1500 х 500 px
>      Фото профиля: 400 x 400 px
>
>      INSTAGRAM
>      Картинка для поста: 1080 x 1080 px
>      Фото профиля: 110 x 110 px
>
>      YOUTUBE
>      Картинка поверх видео: 1280 x 720 px
>      Обложка канала: 2560 x 1440 px
>      Фото профиля: 800 x 800 px
>
>      PINTEREST
>      Картинка для пина: 735 x 1102 px
>      Фото профиля: 165 x 165 px
>
>      LINKEDIN
>      Картинка к внешним ссылкам: 180 х 110 px
>      Картинка для поста: 350 x 230 px
>      Обложка: 646 x 220 px
>      Фото профиля: 400 х 400 px
>
>      GOOGLE+
>      Обложка: 2120 x 1192 px
>      Фото профиля: 250 х 250 px
>
>      OK.RU
>      Картинка для поста: 1680 х 1680 px
>      Обложка: 1340 x 320 px
>      Фото профиля: 190 х 190 px
> ```

**Почему столько разных описаний и требований к разметке?**

*Потому что каждый выдумывает свою:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Подробные обзоры от Яндекса на ХабраХабре про микроразметку помогут вам понять о ней всё:*

1. [Как устроен мир семантической микроразметки](https://habr.com/post/211638/)
2. [Почему разных описаний разметки так много](https://habr.com/post/221881/)
3. [Зачем на самом деле используют микроразметку](https://habr.com/post/229929/)
4. [Микроразметка: зачем ею пользуются и почему она пригодится и вам](https://habr.com/post/246003/)

**В дополнение:**

- Поиск: [Все статьи на ХабраХабре про «микроразметка картинок»](https://google.ru/search?q=%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA+site:habr.com)